# C# Convert dd/MMMM/yyyy to yyyymmdd (Russian)

Tags: c#, datetime

**31 декабря 2016 в 15:10**

декабря is not English.

декабря = December

```
DateTime.Parse("31/December/2016").ToString("yyyymmdd"); => 20161231

DateTime.Parse("31/декабря/2016").ToString("yyyymmdd"); => Error
```

**31 декабря 2016 в 15:10** => 20161231

How do I convert it?

Comment: Go look at `ParseExact` or `TryParseExcact` and set the culture

Comment: I found that using `DateTime.TryParseExact("31/декабря/2016", "dd/MMMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"), DateTimeStyles.None, out result);` then `result.ToString("yyyyMMdd")` will return "20161231" as you want, have you missed something?

Comment: Thanks everyone ! Спасибо

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `DateTime` format above should be converted using `TryParseExact` with `GetCultureInfo` set to Russian culture like this:

```
String example = "31/декабря/2016"; // December 31, 2016

DateTime result;

bool check;
check = DateTime.TryParseExact(example, "dd/MMMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"), DateTimeStyles.None, out result);

String converted = result.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

Console.WriteLine(check);
Console.WriteLine(converted);
```

The output returned by console is:

```
True
20161231
```

NB: To convert date with spaces instead of slashes between date components, change `"dd/MMMM/yyyy"` to `"dd MMMM yyyy"` (use another format to convert time part together).

Working example: [.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AASniA)